# Why is my button overflowing into another page?

Tags: html, css

Here is a picture example of what is happening.

[image: Picture with button overflowing into another page]

I'm trying to build one of those one-page scrolling websites.

The white background indicates one page, the grey background indicates the beginning of another page.

As I start filling my white page with content, I notice that my button slowly starts sliding down and is now encroaching into the grey page.  I don't want that to happen but rather for the white page to extend.

Here is my CSS for the pages:

```
#white-page
{
    background-color: white;
    height: auto;
    min-height: 100vh;
    text-align: center;
}

#grey-page
{
    background-color: grey;
    min-height: 100vh;
}
```

Here is my CSS for the button.

```
.download-center
{
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 60px;   
}

.btn 
{
    text-decoration: none;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    color: inherit;
}
```

Here is the relevant HTML

```
<section id="white-page">
    //page content here
    <div class="download-center">
        <a class="btn font-r" href="docs/resume.pdf" target="_blank">
        <img id="download-pic" src="pic/download.svg" />Download R&eacutesum&eacute
        </a>
    </div>
</section>

<section id="grey-page">
    //page content here
</section>
```

I tried setting the height to `auto` for the white page but it doesn't seem to work.

Basically, I just want the page to extend as the content requires but with a minimum of `vh` so that it takes up the whole of the screen first.

Edit: By removing the `margin-top` property, here is the result.  All it does it pushes the button closer to my content but still encroaches on the page borders.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide life example?

Comment: can you show the html? It could be that the button is inside a div which has `position:absolute;`

Comment: try removing margin-top property from .download-center css

Comment: pls add HTML code also.

Comment: Oops, sorry, I've edited my post to include the relevant HTML.  I've tried removing the `margin-top` property and all it does it it pushes the button up closer to my page content but does not solve the problem of it creeping down as my content increases.

Comment: @noblerare did u find the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm answering my own post because removing margin-top was not the solution that worked for me.  Instead, it was increasing margin-bottom.

```
margin-bottom: 40px;
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason is you have restricted `height` and used `margin-top`:

```
.download-center {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 60px;   
}
```

Adjusting `margin-top` to a lesser value, say `30px` will make the button stay inside.

Comment: I've tried removing the `margin-top` property and this does not seem to work.  I've edited my original post to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

Reduce margin from top and add position as like:

```
.download-center {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 40px;
    position: absulote;    
}
```